# Recording Discord Voice Chat with discord.js results in corrupted Opus files

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, audio-streaming

I am currently trying to develop a Discord bot using discord.js that records user voice chats and outputs them as Opus files. However, I'm running into issues where the outputted Opus files are corrupted and don't contain any data.

Here's a summary of what I've done so far:

1. I've set up the bot to connect to a voice channel and listen to a user's audio stream.
2. I'm using the "@discordjs/opus" package to encode the audio data.
3. When a user starts speaking, I create a write stream to a new Opus file and pipe the user's audio stream into it.

With this setup, I'm able to receive data from the user's audio stream and write it into an Opus file. I know this because I've set up logging at each stage of the process, and it shows that I'm receiving data and writing it into a file when a user speaks.

```
const { OpusEncoder } = require("@discordjs/opus");
const fs = require('fs');
const { Transform } = require("stream");
const dir = './recordings';

function transcriptionDevice(userID, voiceConn, talkingUser, time) {
    console.log('1. Start speaking event triggered');

    const opusPath = `./recordings/${userID}_${time}.opus`;
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(opusPath);

    console.log('2. Created file stream for writing Opus data');

    const { receiver } = voiceConn;
    const audioStream = receiver.subscribe(userID);

    console.log('3. Subscribed to user audio stream');

    audioStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
        // Write data directly to the file
        writeStream.write(chunk);
        console.log('4. Wrote data to file');
    });

    audioStream.on('end', () => {
        console.log("5. Audio stream ended");
        // End the write stream when the audio stream ends
        writeStream.end();
    });

    writeStream.on("finish", () => {
        console.log("6. File write finished");
    });

    audioStream.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('7. An error occurred:', err);
    });
}
```

This is the most recent attempt I have tried, I get all the console logs, and I get the opus file, but again when I open it in VLC or try to convert it to wav with ffmpeg it just reads as a "corrupt" file it opens the program and has 0 data, can't hit play or anything.

I also recently checked my bots permission and I am 90% sure I have the ones I need *connect, speak, voice activity*

Answer (score 0):

```
    function transcriptionDevice(userID, voiceConn, talkingUser, time) {
    console.log('1. Start speaking event triggered');

    const audioReceiveStream = voiceConn.receiver.subscribe(userID,{
        end: {
            behavior: EndBehaviorType.AfterSilence,
            duration: 500,
        }
    }).on('error', (error) => {
        console.log("audioReceiveStream error: ", error);
    });

    const filename = `./recordings/${talkingUser}_${time}.pcm`;
    const out = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    // Create a decoder to decode the Opus audio data into PCM
    const opusDecoder = new prism.opus.Decoder({ frameSize: 960, channels: 2, rate: 48000 });

    // Let's add some logging to the stream to make sure data is flowing
    const logStream = new (require('stream').Transform)({
        transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
            //console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
            callback(null, chunk);
        }
    });

    pipeline(audioReceiveStream, opusDecoder, logStream, out, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
        }
    });
}
```

I have no idea, but if anyone stubles across this recording PCM data works
opus wav and converting pcm to anything else does not work why no idea, how I found this out trail and error but THIS works!